# General advices to create a LaTeX class

Tags: document-classes, documentclass

I have some time working with LaTeX, so I decided to create my own LaTeX class to simplify my preamble and, by the way, learn something I haven't done yet. To get started I looked for some guides as:

- [Overleaf guide to create a class](https://es.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_class)
- [clsguide.pdf](https://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/base/clsguide.pdf)
- and some more (that I forget to keep).

But I still have several questions that I think are not answered on the guides and most of the people that have created a class might have, so we can also compile them on a single question. I'm going to make some questions, feel free to answer any one you'd like to or even add some.

**Questions**

- Why should I use `docstrip` instead of just writing my own .cls?
- If I want to include in the class some code that was answered in *stackexchange* how do I give the credits correctly?
- If I just want some features of a package is it rude to just take the command (with the correct credits)? or does I have to use the entire package?
- When I submit my class to CTAN will it become aviable (just by saying `\documentclass{myclass}` not importing the .cls) on Overleaf? and if not is any way to do that?
- How can I make the class aviable in all my computer without mattering on the directory?
- is it correct to use the `@` symbol in the internal commands of the class?
- And at last, any other advice that you would like to give to a beginner in this stuff?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I try to give my opinion on some of your questions and give an answer on others.

### `docstrip`

*Opinion*

It doesn't really matter. The `docstrip` files keep your sources and documentation in a single file. Some might find this easier to maintain. It allows for neatly formatted implementation comments in the typeset documentation, all while stripping down the production code to a bare minimum (removing all comments except for some licensing stuff, *etc*.). That being said you don't have to write a `docstrip` file. I maintain several packages and three classes myself (not all of it is on CTAN due to very limited scope/small group of interest). None of those classes is written in `docstrip`, some (most?) of the packages are. That's just a matter of taste really.

### Licensing of TeX.SX code

*Answer (but I'm no lawyer)*

The stuff on TeX.SX is licensed under CC BY-SA, that means you must share it under the same (or a compatible?) license if you use code from this site, and you must tell where you got the code (or from whom). Usually a comment in the code (that might get stripped by `docstrip`) telling the user and a link to the answer should suffice, so something like (just the most recent answer on the network as of writing this):

```
% code from Mico (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/627712/117050)
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{$\displaystyle}p{0.333\textwidth}<{$}}
```

That being said, some of us have relicensed their code on this website under different licenses as well (in that case you can choose which license you pick, either the CC BY-SA or the other one). That information is either found on the profile pages or in [this thread](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers).

### Cherry-picking from Packages

*Answer/Opinion*

The packages have a license (usually LPPL, sometimes others, you must check this). If the licenses allow taking code from the package (with or without attribution) you can take code from them. But keep in mind that the code you derived from them has to be maintained. And that means by *you*. In the past this lead to incompatibilities and faulty packages/classes. So my advice here is: Using the entire package is the better idea in probably 99% of the cases.

### CTAN and Overleaf ready?

*Answer*

Overleaf runs a TeX Live installation that gets updated every now and then (once or twice a year, it isn't kept on the bleeding edge). So if your class ends up on CTAN and uses a libre license (like the LPPL) it'll end in TeX Live and will find its way to Overleaf eventually (but this could take a year).

*Opinion*

Do you think your class is relevant to more than a handful of people and/or offers possibilities not there yet? If you don't answer this with "yes" please don't put your package into TeX Live (so don't publish it on CTAN). TeX Live gets bloated enough with other classes used by maybe 2 people.

### Locally installing the Class

*Answer*

In your home folder there should be a `texmf` folder. Inside that create (if necessary) the path `<texmf>/tex/latex/<name-of-class>/` and put a symlink (or a copy) of your `.cls` file into that directory.

Alternatively you can set up the `l3build` tool for your class and just run `l3build install` from the folder of your class to install it locally whenever you have a state that is production ready. And `l3build uninstall` removes the local installation. Also `l3build` allows unit tests, all in all it's a brilliant tool you should look into, imho.

### Internal Commands

*Answer*

Using `@` in internal command names is a LaTeX and plain TeX convention you *might* follow. Technically there is nothing forcing you to do that. But since TeX has no (built in) name spaces you can utilize this to reduce the probability of clashes. When I create a new package I usually search through my TeX Live installation and check whether there are any commands starting with `\<pkg-abbreviation>@` (using `grep` or similar tools). If there are none that becomes the prefix for all my internal commands.

Another possibility would be to code in the programming layer of LaTeX3 (`expl3`), which doesn't use `@` in names, instead macro (and variable) names are structured with `_`.

Comment: After a long answer...also very good built....+1.

Comment: +1 for not uploading to CTAN, especially departmental thesis classes only usable in one institution distributed to the entire world just to save someone setting up a departmental server.