# Multicolumn Shifts Down First Math Formatted Question

Tags: amsmath, multicolumn, multicol

I am trying to have a grid of problems to solve. But the first problem is always shifted down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{flalign*}
        & 1) \int 2x\; dx= &
    \end{flalign*}
    \begin{flalign*}
        & 2) \int -4x\; dx= &
    \end{flalign*}
    \begin{flalign*}
        & 3) \int 6x\; dx= &
    \end{flalign*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Incorrectly formatted questions]

I would like to know what is wrong with my code so that I can get my problems to be in the same row like this:
[image: Correctly formatted questions]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `flalign` here. Since the default for `multicol` is to balance the columns, setting three separate paragraphs with "in-line displays" yields what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
1) $\displaystyle \int  2x\; \mathrm{d}x = {}$

2) $\displaystyle \int -4x\; \mathrm{d}x = {}$

3) $\displaystyle \int  6x\; \mathrm{d}x = {}$
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you so much. That is exactly what I am looking for. I appreciate all the unsaid things in your code like how to remove the indent and how to over-ride automatic style rules using \displaystyle. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Using a `multicols` environment seems like serious overkill for the use case at hand. A plain `tabular` environment will do at least as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{$\displaystyle}p{0.333\textwidth}<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{PPP}
1) \int 2x\,dx= & 2) \int -4x\,dx= & 3) \int 6x\,dx= 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi I think also with alignat. :-))))

Comment: @Mico while technically true, conceptually this is *not* a table.  If you pass this to any post processing tool it will see a table and then reads it out as such (or whatever it does). Once tagged and accessible documents become more mainstream this is no longer describing the content but the visual structure with consequences that are difficult to manage.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach - Thanks for pointing out that the `tabular` approach may cause problems with accessibilty-focused document processors.

Comment: tabular has a long tradition to be (mis)used for visual placement (so you are in good company), but just like the html folks found out that this is not really sustainable we will find that too in the TeX world eventually (at least when you are targetting for more than "great printout"