# Modifying the aomart class to book or report

Tags: document-classes

I am writing some lecture notes using the aomart class, because I like almost everything about it. What I currently dislike is the fact that since it's an article I cannot use chapters and the page is slightly too small. Is it possible to modify these two aspects of the class?
I also accept suggestions for templates that look like aomart but also fulfil my other conditions.

Comment: Maybe you can try modify `\LoadClass[11pt]{amsart}` in `aomart.cls` to `\LoadClass[11pt]{amsbook}`.

Comment: that plus `\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{amsart}}`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Just these two lines one after the other? Would this also make the page slightly larger?

Comment: Thank you, @DavidCarlisle. Karl, you can read in 67 and 71 line in `aomart.cls`. Just modify `amsart` to `amsbook`.

Comment: @Karl no Clara meant copy `aomart.cls` to (say) `mybook.cls` make those changes then use `\documentclass{mybook}`

Comment: do I need to make a .sty file as well and place both in my local tex directory structure or can I just add a mybook.cls file to the global installation?

Comment: what .sty would you make? simplest is to save mybook.cls in the same folder as your document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but with the idea of making it available for other latex projects of mine in the future?

Comment: sure, but get it working first, that's the only part specific to aomart and _this_ question. Making the `.cls` (not `.sty` available generally) is a generic question for which we already have several answers, eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627707/general-advices-to-create-a-latex-class/627713#627713  but just do that once it works

Comment: Thanks. There seems to be a hitch. After changing the class as instructed, the commands \contrib and \contentsnamefont are now undefined

Comment: you provided no example so haven't had a tested answer. You can probably just change `\renewcommand{\contrib}[2][]{%` to `\newcommand{\contrib}[2][]{%` alternatively stick with aomart and just copy `\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi` and following lines from report.cls

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first suggestion worked. As for adjusting the page size, should I invoke geometry from within the cls file and set my preferred size or is there a preferable way?